# Shopify: How to get product json by product ID?

Tags: javascript, ajax, shopify

I am trying to get single product json by product id

```
https://testbydisnap.myshopify.com/products.json?product_id=10282991814
```

OR

```
https://testbydisnap.myshopify.com/products/drummer-tshirt.js
```

replace with

```
https://testbydisnap.myshopify.com/products/10292902662.js
```

Any solution?

Thanks

Comment: Where are you calling this? Shopify has a liquid code that can generate a json file for any product.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use .json at the end of the URL. Your last example was close!

Correct url would be `GET https://testbydisnap.myshopify.com/products/10292902662.json`

If you want to do it via Javascript on the frontend of the site:

```
jQuery.getJSON('/products/a-b-c-d-e.js', function(product) {
  console.log('The tags for this product are ' + product.tags);
} );
```

`The tags for this product are test1,test2`

Comment: This not works .. What do you mean by GET?
How to use that?

Comment: Are you trying to do this via javascript or from a REST client?

Comment: By `GET` I simply mean you'd be using a `GET` request to the server, to retrieve that product.

Comment: /products/a-b-c-d-e.js
a-b-c-d-e (I want to get this via product id)

Answer (score -1):

For getting product json for a single product based on its id, you could simply use:-

https://testbydisnap.myshopify.com/admin/products/**product-id**.json

You can test this url from browser by passing product-id. It will show product information in JSON format.

Comment: this worked only when we are login in shopify admin.